# Required Preconditions for Galactic Formation

Tags: newtonian-gravity, astrophysics, computational-physics, galaxies, structure-formation

In recent weeks, I have been working on building simulations to look at the formation of galaxies from dust clouds. It's a relatively crude simulation at this point as I needed a working model to build on, but I have discovered some odd phenomena:

By creating an initial system composed of a 3d normal distribution of particles (high particle density in the middle, lower on the outsides), and allowing it to condense, it initially forms a high-speed orbital system, but then collapses and throws off most of the particles through the duration of the simulation. (see photos at bottom).

I have noticed some similar phenomena with a central gravitational body.

I have accounted for collisions based on particle size, which works perfectly, thus it isn't an issue of asymptotic acceleration.

Thus, my question is as follows: What underlying variables need to be accounted for to improve the "bare bones" simulation, which uses only gravity, size, and collision? Also, what preconditions are required in order to form a spiral galaxy from the particle cloud? What about an elliptical galaxy? 
[image: Initial Cloud]

[image: Pseudo-galaxy]

[image: Eventual dispersion]

Comment: Particles there are not used enough. In nature, galaxies are not formed from 100 particles. It is necessary to use the approximation of a continuous medium.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, What is the critical density requirement? and what's the underlying physical reasoning behind the requirement of a continuous medium in order to facilitate "formation"?

Comment: Take the mass of the galaxy that you want to describe (typically $M=10^{12}$ solar mass or $2*10^{42} kg$), divide by the mass of particles the galaxy is built of (usually it is a hydrogen atom with $m=1.66*10^{-27} kg$), you get a characteristic number of particles $N=10^{69}$. We cannot describe the motion of such a number of particles; therefore, we use the approximation of a continuous medium.

Comment: Depending what you want to do with your 'galaxy', there are several possible approaches. As a general statement, gravity is scale-free on even cosmic scales (GR effects are weak), so what you simulate here might be a star cluster, or an elliptic galaxy, depending only on how you rescale x and t. If you just want to see some discy object, then add initial angular momentum to your particles, or let their initial separation be increased. If you want to see spirals, there are criteria for that, working both in continuum and n-bodies. A continuum approach is necessary for a complete galaxy,

Comment: because galaxies usually possess an important fraction of their visible (baryonic) mass in gas ($\sim$30% for the milky way) and the rest of the baryonic mass in stars. Note that galaxies possess dark-matter halos which are up to $\sim$ 100 times more massive than the baryonic component. When you see outcomes of large-scale cosmological simulations (e.g. the millenium simulations) that show thousands of galaxies, what is usually shown is this dark-matter component. So you see, depending on your ambition, there's many things to do.

Comment: You're not going to get "spiral galaxies" from this because there's no dissipation. Spiral galaxies form because gas clouds collide and lose energy, which in turn is radiated away, cooling the gas; the result is collapse into a disk which conserves angular moment. (Not unlike how the Solar System formed.)

Comment: @AlexTrounev If you want to simulate a gas-free galaxy, then you absolutely have to use particles; stars do not form a "continuous medium". But you need a *lot* of particles, generally in the millions.

Comment: You don't mention how you do the calculations; I suspect you are not using gravitational softening, and the "evaporation" of most of the particles is probably a result of two-body interactions (two particles passing close to each other and strongly influencing their trajectories). This is a known effect for systems with small numbers of particles, and is even theorized to happen in some globular clusters (though the process takes billions of years).

Comment: @PeterErwin Even galaxies form a continuous medium on a large scale. Stars also form a continuous galactic-scale medium. But of course we can use the method of large particles for simulation.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Yes, it's a very useful approximation to treat galaxies as collisionless stellar fluids. It's only an approximation, however, and if we could, we would treat the stars (properly) as particles, as is done in simulations of globular clusters and the Galactic Center (e.g., [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.02153)).

Comment: @PeterErwin I thank for the link, there they consider the formation of a cluster around the BH. This is a simpler problem than galaxy formation.